# Excel Function for looking at text in a cell

Tags: excel, function, dax

My goal is to enter in column E on sheet 2 whether or not the customer used the discount code "BUNDLE3".
I would like to look at the order number in sheet 2 represented by column A then look at Column A in sheet 1 (where my orders data is) and if they match, then look at column M(discount code column in sheet 1) and if Column M has the text "BUNDLE3" then return Yes, if not return No.

The formula I was using is the one below, where orders_export_1 is sheet 1. It doesn't work because its not looking at the order numbers at all.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BUNDLE3",orders_export_1!M2)), "Yes", "No")
```

Please refer to image links for more clarity.

[sheet 2, where I am trying to use an excel function in order to find out if an order (represented by column A) used the discount code "BUNDLE3"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uitvw.png)

[sheet 1, This is my orders data. Sometimes orders take up multiple rows since they are listing the products customers have purchased.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vbce.png)

Comment: Maybe you could try something like =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!M:M,"BUNDLE3")>=1,"Yes","No")

Answer (score 1):

In `Sheet2`, E2, put this formula and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(orders_export_1!$A$2:$A$100,A2,orders_export_1!$M$2:$M$100,"BUNDLE3"),"Yes","No")
```

Adjust the range on `orders_export_1` as needed.

Comment: You are a hero. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexZamora - If this works, you can mark it as The Answer by ticking the check mark to the left of the post. Glad to help!